# whats wrong in this asp.net webusercontrol code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have updated my code but it still not working ...

after i run my asp.net webpage and click on button the following error occurs everytime ...

***Microsoft JScript runtime error: Exception thrown and not caught***

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="WebUserControl" %>
<script src="./scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#chkAll').click(
    function() {
        $("INPUT[type='button']").attr('click', $('#chkAll').is(':click'));
    });
});   
     </script>
    <div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="chkAll" type="button" value="button" />
</asp:Panel>
    </div>
```

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Exception thrown and not caught

Comment: What would you like to happen? btw: in the jQuery include: are you sure it's . and not .. at the begining?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code?  What does `$("INPUT[type='button']").attr('click', $('#chkAll').is(':click'));` do?

Comment: Also showing this erro in jquery :


Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
 throw "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg;
};

Comment: i want when button is clicked then all the checkbox will be checked and unchecked....

Comment: @pooja: That's not an error.  That's a line of code that would display an error if it's given one.  Has it been given one?  Can we see it?

Comment: ya this showing the error : i thing button attributes are wrong and i dont know what to do there :

 $("INPUT[type='button']").attr('click', $('#chkAll').is(':click'));

Answer (score 3):

You don't need #<%=chkAll.ClientID %> for controls that don't have runat="server"
Just use the ID.

Comment: then where to modify this code to use ...button instead of checkbox as chkAll

Comment: $('#<%=chkAll.ClientID %>') sould be $('#chkAll'). This will solve your error.

Comment: Now this erro will comes up

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Exception thrown and not caught

Comment: You asked about the "Name chkAll is not declared", and that's the solution. If you have other errors, please update your post with the exact error and what you would like to do, or maybe open a new question for a new error :)

Comment: @pooja: It looks like there's a second reference to `chkAll.ClientID` in your JavaScript code which also needs to be changed.  Further, once you've changed it and tried your test again, if it still fails please edit the question to include the new code and the full text of the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do exactly what's being demonstrated [here](http://jetlogs.org/jquery/jquery_select_all.html).  From that demo:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#paradigm_all").click(function()               
  {
    var checked_status = this.checked;
    $("input[@name=paradigm]").each(function()
    {
      this.checked = checked_status;
    });
  });                   
});
```

Note the key differences between what this is doing and what your code is doing.  You are selecting inputs of type `button` and trying to change a property on them called `click`.  That... won't work.  This demo is instead selecting some inputs of type `checkbox` by name and setting their `checked` status.  Additionally, it's doing it by use of a `checkbox` rather than a `button` (which appears to be your stated intention).

You can read up on jQuery selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).  There's a lot you can use for selecting elements.  In the demo, the elements have the same `name` attribute and can be selected as such.  You should be able to set `name` properties in your .NET server controls for use on client-side code just as easily.  Without `name` attributes, you could alternatively select them child elements of your `Panel`, or your `div`, etc.  You may want to give some names or ids in there just to make it easy on yourself.

**Edit:** Based on your comment, you can just change the logic a little bit.  You'd still bind to the click event as before.  However, you wouldn't be able to use the elements own `checked` status, since a button doesn't have one.  Something like this, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#paradigm_all").click(function()                
  {
    $(":checkbox").each(function()
    {
      this.checked = true;
    });
  });                    
});
```

This modifies the logic of the previous example (assuming you've changed the target checkbox to a button in the markup).  The main differences are:

- The selector for the other checkboxes now selects all checkboxes on the page.  You'll probably want to target a more specific selector than this, but it works for the purpose of the demo.
- The button only sets all checkboxes to checked.  With this example, clicking the button again doesn't un-check them.  To accomplish that you'd have to define a bit more logic.  For example, if some of them are checked and the button is clicked, do they all check or all un-check?  Or do they toggle?  What if the user uses the button to check all and then un-checks one?  Upon clicking the button again, does the one get re-checked or do the rest get un-checked?  Lots of UX questions :)

Comment: I want button instead of selectall checkbox